# What do these macros and typedefs do? How to expand it to member functions?

Tags: c++, c, dll

I'm trying to understand this piece of code and expand on it.
I've added some comments on what I think it does, but could someone clarify.
One is a dynamic-link library, and the other is the executable. They're compiled separately.

In the DLL's header file:

```
#define INITIALIZE_WINDOW(name) void name()
// ^ Macro replacing all instances of INITIALIZE_WINDOW

typedef INITIALIZE_WINDOW(initialize_window);
// ^ Equivalent to typedef void initialize_window();
// ^ What's the purpose of this statement? Is it to let the executable know about its existence?
```

In the DLL's source file:

```
INITIALIZE_WINDOW(InitializeWindow) { /* Do stuff */ }
// ^ Equivalent to void InitializeWindow();
// ^ GetProcAddress() gets an address to this function
```

In the executable's source file:

```
initialize_window* initializeWindow = (initialize_window*)GetProcAddress(dllHandle, "InitializeWindow");
// ^ Retrieve the address of InitializeWindow() but cast it as an initialize_window pointer?
// ^ Equivalent to void (*initializeWindow)() = (initialize_window*)GetProcAddress(...); Is this correct?
```

Eventually expanding on this. How would I macro member functions and use GetProcAddress() for them?

Comment: You cannot and should not use `GetProcAddress` on member functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The goal of the macro is to enforce the correct type.

You did the correct replacement:

```
typedef INITIALIZE_WINDOW(initialize_window);
```

is equivalent to

```
using initialize_window = void (); // function taking nothing returning void
```

and so `initialize_window*` is a function pointer (`void(*)()`).

definition of the function InitializeWindow:

```
void InitializeWindow() {/**/}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's a function typedef.

`typedef void initialize_window()` makes `initialize_window` an alias for the type `void()` which is a function type taking no parameters (in C++) or taking an unspecified but constant number of parameters (in C), and returning `void`.

`initialize_window*` is therefore a pointer to type `void()`, i.e. `void(*)()`, i.e. a function pointer.